# Error, when saving nickname to mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm using Steam API and after login I save user nickname to the database.
I'm getting the error when nickname contains Russian words or special symbols like ʊ ϟ ღ 回 ₪. In database nickname type - varchar.
[Mysql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDLph.png)

```
connection.query("
    INSERT INTO users 
        ('steamid', 'nickname', 'avatar', 'tradelink')
    VALUES
        ('" + req.user.id + "', '" + req.user._json.personaname + "', '" + req.user._json.avatarfull + "', ' ')
")
```

Comment: And the error message is? Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Do you got the specifics of your SQL table? We need to know how you build up your table

Comment: Here is an error - Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xCF\x9F' for column 'nickname' at row 1

Comment: This is a naming convention issue. If you don't provide us with the query that you used to create the table you need to read up about it over here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the charset of the table to `utf8mb4`.

```
ALTER TABLE users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

There was a great article covering why you should not use `utf8` and instead use `utf8mb4` yesterday, which you can read [here](http://www.eversql.com/mysql-utf8-vs-utf8mb4-whats-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf8mb4/).

Comment: After this I'm getting this:
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected.

Comment: You need to select which database to run the query on. What tool do you use to interface with the database? The MySQL Command-Line Tool or something like phpMyAdmin?